# How to copy of the shape object in office js powerpoint addin

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

How do I copy a shape object using PowerPoint office-js APIs?

Are there any Javascript office-js APIs for creating copies of selected shapes?

By clicking a button in the taskpane, I want to copy a shape. The copied shape should use the office-js APIs to copy the selected shape object.

[image]
I was creating a add-in like the attached image. I want to create selected shapes by increasing the count

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.